# Size video playback to UIView size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avfoundation

I have a UIView that is based on VideoPlayer Class, When I open the video file it does not 'fit' the bounds of the UIView. This causes the top and bottom to be outside the UIView and a cannot see the play-back controls.

I have tried setting the 'Content Mode' to Scale to fit, Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill etc. but it has no affect.

How can I make it 'fill' the UIView?

The PlayerViewClass:

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass{
        return AVPlayerLayer.self;
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer{
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    var player: AVPlayer?{
        get{
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set{
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

In my main ViewController.swift class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: PlayerViewlass!
    func getCacheDirectory () -> URL {
    // return the documents url
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let docsUrl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    return docsUrl
}

func getFileURL() -> URL{
    // Get url of the file
    let path = getCacheDirectory()
    let filePath = path.appendingPathComponent("\(videoFileName)")
    return filePath
}

@IBAction func playVideoFile(_ sender: Any) {
    let path = getFileURL()
    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
    cameraView.playerLayer.player = player
    cameraView.player?.play()
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this? I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: you would have to show the code you are using to place the view, where are you configuring Its frame?

Comment: the code is above in the function:playVideoFile

Comment: No. There is no code you are configuring the frame. Is your issue view is bigger then PlayerViewClass frame? Why don't you change PlayerViewClass frame to support the size you would like